# Toggle Developer Dashboard not working

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, stsadm

I just ran the following as administrator

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn developer-dashboard -pv ondemand
```

The operation completed successfully.  I see the icon to the right of my name and attempt to toggle the view.  When I click the icon, the screen flashes and nothing else happens.  If I set

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn developer-dashboard -pv on
```

Then, the dashboard shows with no problems. This is Win7 IE8

Cheers.

Comment: Revisiting this thread.  One notable is that it works fine in Firefox.  It will not work in IE.

Comment: did you check in compatibilty view for IE ?

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, I have a bad install. I stood up another box and instance.  The command works flawless on this machine.

Comment: It probably works because there are different settings for compatibility mode in IE. Press F12 in IE and make sure it is selected like on this picture: http://postimg.org/image/m9mbo2zb5/